# Short story where Walt Disney is thawed from cryo-storage to rule over Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, disney

I read a tongue-in-cheek short story in the 1970s / 1980s with an anniversary setting for the Disney Corporation, thawing the frozen corpse of Walt Disney to return as CEO and ruler of Earth … after the nuclear attack from Disney World succeeds. Nuclear missiles hidden in the Dumbo Elephant rides, among other places. I’m looking for author and title.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I remember that story, but, alas, not the title or author - nor can my decent googling skills find it.

Comment: Do you remember where you saw it: in a magazine, or an anthology, or whatever?

Comment: @Clara, it was an anthology … Best Of (year | forever) … it was a long time ago …